# Step on canonical quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, fourier-transform, hamiltonian

So I've been trying to solve the expression for the Hamiltonian using the canonical quantization of a complex scalar field and I am not sure of how the following step comes by, from

$$\mathcal{H} = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{2 E_p} \left[ 2 E_{p}^2 \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p} \hat{a}_p + \hat{b}_p \hat{b}^{\dagger}_p  \right )- 2 \vec{p}^2 \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p} \hat{b}^{\dagger}_{-p} e^{2i E_p t} +\hat{b}_p \hat{a}_{-p} e^{-2i E_p t} \right )\right ]$$

to

$$\mathcal{H} = \int d^3 \vec{p} \  E_{p} \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p} \hat{a}_p + \hat{b}_p \hat{b}^{\dagger}_p  \right ).$$

Does it have anything to do with the commutation relations with respect to $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p} \hat{b}^{\dagger}_{-p}$ and $\hat{b}_p \hat{a}_{-p}$ under the integration over $p$?

Comment: Can you provide the source from which this step come from?

Comment: @LeoL. I have made the calculations myself, but in this link they make the same procedure as I, although I don't understand their statement from equation (22) to (24).

https://physicspages.com/pdf/Lahiri%20QFT/Lahiri%20&%20Pal%20Problems%2003.08.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equation appears to be wrong. You should obtain an equation of the form 
$$\mathcal{H} = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{2 E_p} \left[  (E_{p}^2+p^2+m^2) \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p} \hat{a}_p + \hat{b}_p \hat{b}^{\dagger}_p  \right )+ (-E_{p}^2+p^2+m^2) \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p} \hat{b}^{\dagger}_{-p} e^{2i E_p t} +\hat{b}_p \hat{a}_{-p} e^{-2i E_p t} \right )\right ]$$

And then you can use the on-shell condition $E_{p}^2=p^2+m^2$ to eliminate the 2nd term and simplify the first term to obtain

$$\mathcal{H} = \int d^3 \vec{p} \  E_{p} \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{p} \hat{a}_p + \hat{b}_p \hat{b}^{\dagger}_p  \right ).$$